# Weak convergence of combinations of $x_n$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ a Banach space and let $\{u_n\}\subset V$ such that $u_n\longrightarrow u$ in $\sigma(V,V^*)$.

Let
$$
v_n=\frac{u_1+\ldots+u_n}{n}
$$
Show that $v_n\longrightarrow u$ in $\sigma(V,V^*)$.

My attempt:

Note that
\begin{align*}
    \left|f\left(\frac{u_1+\ldots+u_n}{n}\right)-f(u)\right|
    &=\left|f\left(\frac{u_1+\ldots+u_n}{n}\right)-\frac{nf(u)}{n}\right|\\
    &=\frac{1}{n}\left|f\left(u_1+\ldots+ u_n\right)-nf(u)\right|\\
    &=\frac{1}{n}\left|f(u_1-u)+\ldots+f(u_n-u)\right|\\
    &\leqslant\frac{1}{n}(|f(u_1-u)|+\ldots+|f(u_n-u)|)\\
\end{align*}
We know that $f(u_n-u)$ is bounded, follows that exists $L>0$ such that $|f(u_n-u)|<L$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. How $u_n\longrightarrow u$, we have $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for $n\geqslant n_0$ we have $|f(u_n-u)|<\varepsilon$. Furthermore, being $n<n_0$ we see that
\begin{align*}
    &\frac{1}{n}\left(|f(u_1-u)|+\ldots+|f(u_{n_0-1}-u)|+|f(u_{n_0}-u)|+\ldots+|f(u_n-u)|\right)\\
    &\leqslant\frac{1}{n}\left(L+\ldots+L+\varepsilon+\ldots+\varepsilon\right)\\
    &=\frac{(n_0-1)L}{n}+\frac{(n-n_0-1)\varepsilon}{n}\\
    &<\frac{(n_0-1)L}{n}+\varepsilon
\end{align*}
From $\varepsilon$ and $n_0$ arbitrary, letting $n\longrightarrow\infty$ follow the result.

It's correct?

Comment: It suffices to apply the property of numerical sequences: if $a_n\to a$ then $(a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n)/n\to a.$

Comment: It is the Lemma of Cesaro.